# Problem with comparing java.time.LocalDate with postgres date

Tags: java, postgresql, kotlin

I have a problem with downloading a record from a database for which the date, in the form in a database, looks like this: 2018-10-14 (date)

The structure in the database of this field looks like this: next_day DATE NOT NULL

When you call the findDay method, an exception is thrown:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: date <= bytea
```

a method:

```
open fun findDay(day: LocalDate) : Day {
val sql = "SELECT bbd FROM com.test.entity.Day d WHERE d.nextDay <= :nextDay ORDER BY d.nextDay DESC"
val query: TypedQuery<Day> = entityManager.createQuery(sql, Day::class.java)
            query.setParameter("nextDay", day)
            query.maxResults = 1
    return query.singleResult
}
```

entity:

```
@Entity(name="day")
open class Day {

    @Id
     var id: Long? = null

    @Column(name = "next_day")
    var nextDay: LocalDate? = null
}
```

Is there a way for me to get row from the database?

Answer (score 2):

You are using a `LocalDate` as parameter: `day`, but your `entityManager` does only understand `java.util.Date`. You can convert like this:

```
Date date = Date.from(day.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
```

The JPA 2.2 release does support the new Date API.
https://vladmihalcea.com/whats-new-in-jpa-2-2-java-8-date-and-time-types/

Answer (score 0):

This happens in PostgreSQL an when using Hibernate and the parameter value is null. One way to avoid it is by telling it what the type is using a non-null value.

Have some static constant `EPOCH = LocalDate.of(1970, 1, 1)` as an optimization to avoid all the checks and allocations on every call.

```
val query: TypedQuery<Day> = entityManager.createQuery(sql, Day::class.java)
            query.setParameter("nextDay", EPOCH)
            query.setParameter("nextDay", day)
            query.maxResults = 1
    return query.singleResult
```

Of course this will throw you a `NoResultException`, because essentially you're asking `anything <= NULL` which by definition is false, meaning no rows will match.